# Why does Rstudio library fail due to libgfortran dylib, but works in base R

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, gfortran, dylib

### The problem

Using Rstudio, I installed `edgeR` using `BiocManager::install("edgeR")` which went fine. When running `library(edgeR)`, I get an error involving some libgfortran.5.dylib:

```
Loading required package: limma
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘edgeR’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/sbouhad2/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/edgeR/libs/edgeR.so':
  dlopen(/Users/sbouhad2/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/edgeR/libs/edgeR.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0/libgfortran.5.dylib
  Referenced from: <7A0E0743-72B0-3B24-A4BB-8E34A69B6095> /Users/sbouhad2/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/edgeR/libs/edgeR.so
  Reason: tried: '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

When I open a terminal in the default MacOS application or in Rstudio and run `R` followed by `library(edgeR)`, all goes well and I can run functions within the package. I have no idea where to look or how to solve this. I am also not familiar with the technicalities w.r.t. x86 and arm64.

### Session info

For Rstudio, after running the failing library command

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/Amsterdam
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] limma_3.55.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0  tools_4.3.0     rstudioapi_0.14 Rcpp_1.0.10    
[5] grid_4.3.0      locfit_1.5-9.7  lattice_0.21-8
```

For base R, after running the working library command using a terminal

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

time zone: Europe/Amsterdam
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] edgeR_3.41.8 limma_3.55.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0 Rcpp_1.0.10    grid_4.3.0     locfit_1.5-9.7 lattice_0.21-8
```

I can't see any difference except maybe that BLAS has a different path.

---

### Relevant (?) background info

I installed gcc and gfortran using (arch -arm64) homebrew to compile Rcpp packages on a MacOS. After a long search I found out that I need to create `~/.R/Makevars` which now comprises of:

```
CC=gcc-13
CXX=g++-13
FLIBS   =-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib
F77     = /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran
FC      = /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran
```

With this modification, I could build Rcpp packages. Since then, edgeR fails to load within Rstudio.

---

I tried `dyn.load` some of the paths, such as `dyn.load("/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0/libgfortran.5.dylib")`. That didn't work in Rstudio nor in base R.

Also, `library` of the Rcpp based package works and I can execute the code in R and Rstudio.

I don't have any other idea what I could do.

Comment: I don't know why you see that difference, but you shouldn't be mixing homebrew builds with CRAN builds.  If you got R from CRAN, you should use the same compilers to build packages as CRAN uses.  See https://mac.r-project.org/tools/ for what they use.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Do not use this expression, it does not say anythingnuseful. What happened? Was there any error message? Some other output?

Comment: I will just note that we get disproportionally large number of questions having problems with the gfortran runtime libraries on MacOS. Something is wrong with this OS or at least with GCC bundling in it.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава:  The origin of the MacOS problem may be that Apple dropped support for Fortran quite a while ago.  They supply a toolchain (XCode, without Fortran), and there are at least a couple of user contributed toolchains (Homebrew, Macports), and several builds of gfortran which use incompatible runtime libraries.  I don't think GCC is involved in the current question:  R is built with Apple's Xcode and gfortran from https://github.com/R-macos/gcc-12-branch/releases .

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава and 
@user2554330, thanks for the response. I understand that MacOS and R aren't best friends, but what puzzled me is that `library(edgeR)` in R works fine but not in RStudio. Would you have any idea which direction I should investigate?

Comment: This class of problems (compilers and directory paths) is covered in great detail on the mailing list r-sig-mac.  You might find solutions by searching the archives.  The procedures are definitely different for different revisions of MacOS as well as the CPU type in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guided by the comments of @user2554330 and others, I installed gfortran from https://mac.r-project.org/tools/. After restarting RStudio, `library(edgeR)` works!